# Canonical Question about Entropy

Tags: discussion

Is there (or should there be) a canonical question/answer about entropy? Or more specifically, about the various definitions of the term entropy and their relationship?

It seem like everyday there is some [new horribly-confused question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737560/why-do-the-units-of-entropy-include-energy-and-temperature) about "entropy." It seem to be a similar situation as questions about the word "time" or the "flow of time," for which we have a canonical question and answers.

I've seen a number of good answers on main regarding entropy that differentiate between various meanings of the word in physics and make an attempt to reconcile the various definitions ($dQ/T$, $k\log(\Omega)$, $\sum p\log(p)$), but I'm not aware of a canonical question/answer.

To make matters worse, we have software people pretending like you can "calculate the entropy of a file" [or of a password](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737448/does-it-make-physical-sense-to-assign-an-entropy-to-a-microstate), which is getting really far afield from a realistic and meaningful use of information entropy.

So, is it time for a canonical answer about that various definitions of the word entropy?

Comment: Are you asking permission to write one? Or offering the idea for someone else to write it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process of writing a canonical question, but I would take a shot if I knew how. Or if someone else wants to take the idea and write it, that is fine by me.